# How to convert JSON data from a file into a CSV file in C++?

Tags: c++, json, csv, jsoncons

My complete task is to:

- Read a CSV file
- Parse it into Json file
- Do some operations
- Convert the resulting JSON into CSV again.

I am using [jsoncons](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/) library because it allows me to work on JSON and CSV simultaneously.
While I am able to parse csv data into json and perform operations; I got no clue how I can write JSON data back to CSV.

I am going through documentation of jsoncons library, but not been able to figure it out.

Here is a code snippet of parsing CSV data into JSON:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <jsoncons/json.hpp>
#include <jsoncons_ext/csv/csv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace jsoncons;
using namespace jsoncons::csv;

int main()
{
 fstream file;
    file.open("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Csv1\\smallExportCSV.csv");


    csv::csv_options options;
    options.assume_header(true);

    // Parse the CSV data into an ojson value
    ojson j = csv::decode_csv<ojson>(file, options);

    // Pretty print
    json_options print_options;
    print_options.float_format(float_chars_format::fixed);
    std::cout << "\n" << pretty_print(j, print_options) << "\n\n";
}
```

I am new to jsoncons.

Comment: [`encode_csv`](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/blob/master/doc/ref/csv/encode_csv.md)

Comment: Hi @zdf where should I use it ?                                  like- ```ojson j = csv::encode_csv<ojson>(file, options);```

Comment: See the example in the linked page.